# ¿Por qué no muestra nada en consola al llamar al método?

Tags: java

Este es el ejercicio:
Desarrolla un programa JAVA que muestre los recursos del sistema. 
Nota: usa los comandos: free –mt; df; ps; fdisk –l.

Esto es lo que yo he realizado

```
Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean salir = false;
        int opcion; // Guardaremos la opcion del usuario

        while (!salir) {
            System.out.println("*********************************************");
            System.out.println("1. Comando free-mt");
            System.out.println("2. Comando df");
            System.out.println("3. Comando ps");
            System.out.println("4. Comando fdisk –l");
            System.out.println("0. Salir");
            System.out.println("*********************************************");
            System.out.println("Elija una de las opciones");
            opcion = Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine());
            switch (opcion) {
                case 1:
                    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ipconfig");
                    InputStream inputstream = process.getInputStream();
                    BufferedInputStream bufferedinputstream = new BufferedInputStream(inputstream);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Process process2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("df");
                    InputStream inputstream2 = process2.getInputStream();
                    BufferedInputStream bufferedinputstream2 = new BufferedInputStream(inputstream2);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    Process process3 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps");
                    InputStream inputstream3 = process3.getInputStream();
                    BufferedInputStream bufferedinputstream3 = new BufferedInputStream(inputstream3);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Process process4 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("fdisk –l");
                    InputStream inputstream4 = process4.getInputStream();
                    BufferedInputStream bufferedinputstream4 = new BufferedInputStream(inputstream4);
                    break;
                case 0:
                    salir = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Solo numeros entre 0 y 4");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

se que son comandos de linux pero por eso he puesto el ipconfig para probarlo.
El problema es que al hecharlo andar no da nada osea el programa finaliza y no sale la informacion del comando por pantalla

Comment: y el método main?

Comment: es ese esta todo en el main :')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas ejecutar los procesos dentro de un bloque `try ... catch`, y también las lecturas de buffer.

Para no hacer el código tan repetitivo, puedes implementar un método `showCommand`, al cual le pasas el comando desde el bloque `switch` directamente.

Por ejemplo:

```
Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean salir = false;
int opcion; // Guardaremos la opcion del usuario

    while (!salir) {
        System.out.println("*********************************************");
        System.out.println("1. Comando free-mt");
        System.out.println("2. Comando df");
        System.out.println("3. Comando ps");
        System.out.println("4. Comando fdisk –l");
        System.out.println("0. Salir");
        System.out.println("*********************************************");
        System.out.println("Elija una de las opciones");
        opcion = Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine());

        switch (opcion) {
            case 0:
                salir = true;
                break;
            case 1:
                showCommand("ipconfig");
                break;
            case 2:
                showCommand("df");
                break;
             case 3:
                showCommand("ps");
                break;
            case 4:
                showCommand("fdisk –l");
                break;        
            default:
                System.out.println("Solo numeros entre 0 y 4");
        }
    }
```

Y este sería el método:

```
private void showCommand (String cmd) {
    Process theProcess = null;
    try
      {
        theProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
      }

      catch (IOException e)
      {
         System.err.println("Error en el método exec()");
         e.printStackTrace();  
      }

    try
      {
         BufferedReader inStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(theProcess.getInputStream()));  
         System.out.println(inStream.readLine());
      }
      catch(IOException e)
      {
         System.err.println("Error en inStream.readLine()");
         e.printStackTrace();  
      } 
}
```